# add more than one value to an XML property

Tags: html, xml

my question is whether you can add a value or a statement in a property of a component

```
<groupbox parent="" name="6b61b93d-50d1-4803-89f7-8d08099e7f18" label="" x="0" y="2827" w="331" h="189" color="" enabled="True" visible="True" visibleentriesruleid="ES_COMPRADOR_1" flowstyle="Strict" />
```

add another value in the field

```
visibleentriesruleid = "ES_COMPRADOR_1"
```

what I want is that if the value does not arrive `ES_COMPRADOR_1` take the following value that I added that would be `ES_COMPRADOR_2`

Can be done?

Comment: I dont understand the question. As the name implies, XML is a markup language, so without the addition of a programming language, there is no dynamic properties or anything like that. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this with inline [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
visibleentriesruleid="ES_COMPRADOR_1 ? ES_COMPRADOR_1 : ES_COMPRADOR_2"
```

So your code will be:

```
<groupbox parent="" name="6b61b93d-50d1-4803-89f7-8d08099e7f18" label="" x="0" y="2827" w="331" h="189" color="" enabled="True" visible="True" visibleentriesruleid="ES_COMPRADOR_1 ? ES_COMPRADOR_1 : ES_COMPRADOR_2" flowstyle="Strict" />
```